# Classification of t-structures in derived category of R-mod?

Tags: reference-request, derived-categories

I am looking for a reference talking about the complete(or not)description of t-structures in bounded derived category of $R-mod$, i.e. $D^b(R-mod)$.where $R$ is commutative ring, in particular, polynomial ring, say $C[x]$.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on whether you are interested in the derived category of all $R$-modules, or only of finitely generated $R$-modules (if $R$ is noetherian). In the second case the answer should be much more complicated. Although, in the case when $R$ has homological dimension 1 (e.g. for $R = C[x]$), it should be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided $R$ has a dualizing complex an answer is given in [this (very nice) preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0499) of Alonso, Jeremias, and, Saorin in terms of certain filtrations on the spectrum of $R$. Corollary 6.11 is the result you are after.